# Store Dependent JPA Entity as JSON Column In Parent Entity

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson

I have a parent entity like so:

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Convert(converter = ChildConverter.class)
    private Collection<Child> children;
    ...
}
```

And the child entity is defined like so:

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    ...
}
```

However, I want my `Child` entity to be **saved not in its own table but as a (JSON) column in the `Parent` table**. The reason I want to do this is because the `Child` entity contains little data and I feel as if it does not warrant its own table. Is this possible for JPA?

**Update**:

In the end, I've decided to simply not annotate the `Child` class with `@Entity`. But the trouble this brings is that I have to enforce *entity* constraints without JPA's help.

Comment: If the collection is of an entity then that needs to be a relation, and so `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToMany`. You can only use an AttributeConverter if the element type is not an entity (e.g String, Date etc)

Answer (score 0):

You still need a table to store the children of parents, because you use a Collection in the Parent class.

You may use @Embeddable annotation on Child class and @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable on children Collection in the Parent class.

```
@Embeddable
public class Child implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String id;
  ...
}
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Convert(converter = ChildConverter.class)
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
       name="CHILD",
       joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
  private Collection<Child> children;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah. But that would still leave me with a table for `Child` objects, right?